# Cost / Benefit of partitioning tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, database-partitioning, database-indexes

We have 46,081 courses in our COURSE table this number remains relatively static.

We have an average of 7,000 sections added per term (Fall, Spring, Summer) added around the same time.

We have around 320,000 registration rows per term (Fall, Spring, Summer) added gradually through the entire semester with some peaks.

I would like to do a partition by the TERM_CODE on the SECTION table, then do a partition by Reference on the REGISTRATION table.

Is the Reference Type of constraint the best one to choose here?

Comment: Why are you worrying about partitioning with these very small numbers?

Comment: First of all, what problem are you trying to solve by partitioning?

Comment: There is no problem now but I think you can't create a partition after the table has already been created and want to do it in the beginning if possible. To me 900k rows a year is a big number.

Comment: @stan - You have not worked in a bank. 900K records is nothing. It is not a lot for a lap top computer either.